# How do we let app users know connections are made over SSL?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ssl

What is the standard procedure for indicating to a user that the app they are in is transferring data over a secured connection? I know mobile Safari displays a lock above the URL, but I wasn't sure what we should do within our apps.

Bank of America displays a lock and "Secure Area" on their login page. Is this tied into a verification service like Verisign, or is it just a graphic to give the illusion of a security reassurance?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Unless it links to the Verisign website for confirmation, it probably isn't an official badge.

Answer (score 0):

Bank of America uses the same fraud protection, encryption and secure sign-in as their Online Banking. The lock icon is just for letting the users of the application know that their data is being transmitted securely.